# How to find true source of a mount?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I want to understand how can I figure out the actual source of a mount from /proc/self/mountinfo file?

Here is an example of a mountinfo file:

```
19 60 0:5 / /dev rw,nosuid shared:2 - devtmpfs devtmpfs rw,seclabel,size=1930460k,nr_inodes=482615,mode=755
119 74 0:5 /sda1 /home/abc/def rw,nosuid shared:2 - devtmpfs devtmpfs rw,seclabel,size=1930460k,nr_inodes=482615,mode=755
```

Here from the first entry we can see that devtmpfs is mounted to /dev.

In the next line we can that devtmpfs is mentioned as the source. But we already know that it is mounted on /dev. So what should be the real mount source for /home/abc/def?

Should it be /dev?

Comment: Please also show in your question the output of `mount`. Please explain in your question what you want to achieve. Why don't you reed `/proc/self/mounts`?

Comment: Do not assume that a filesystem can be mounted only on one place. That might be true for other Unix systems but is not true for Linux.

Comment: Consider that each new "mount" is a new instance of a filesystem, not necessarily a link to the same (single) instance.